# javascript created choice field values wont save

Tags: dropdown

Im using jquery and getJSON to populate a drop down list based on user input in a custom modified NewForm.aspx. The dropdown populates just fine but when the form is saved the selected choice value is not saved. Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to pinpoint it exactly. But at a high level, the selected value in the generated drop down needs to be pushed to a hidden list field so it can be submitted and saved.

Comment: Thanks Pirate, That is what I am figuring out. Can you access/update the hidden field list with just jquery or do you need to use the SP COM for js? Also how do you find the hidden list? Thanks for your time

Comment: You can use jQuery for that so long as you get the right selector for your form field.

Comment: Anyway to find the corresponding hidden field? A lookup field will have an optHid attribute that gives the id of its hidden field but the choice field does not have one. I did a search on the html output on all the input type='hidden' and could not find anything.